# TypeError: AnonimousSurvey() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python-3.x, class

I searched for some solution but I did not miss self after defining method I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
def AnonimousSurvey():
    
    def __init__(self, question):
        
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []
        
    def show_question(self):
        print(self.question)
        
    def store_response(self, new_response):
        self.responses.append(new_response)
        
    def show_result(self):
        print("Survay results:")
        for i in self.responses:
            print("- " + i)
quest = "hello what is your name?"
new_surv = AnonimousSurvey(quest)
new_surv.show_question()
```

[image: YOu can find screenshot here]

Comment: Please update your question  with code here

Comment: I added code in the main post

Answer (score 1):

Solved I use def instead of Class at the beginning of the script